# Issue With Foreign Key in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I run this code then get an error

> There is no ViewData item of type '`IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`' that has the key '`CourseId`'

Model

Student.cs

```cs
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }
public int CourseId { get; set; }  
public Course course { get; set; }
```

Course.cs

```cs
public class Course
{ 
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

StudentController.cs

```cs
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> CourseId = new List<SelectListItem>();
            CourseId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
            CourseId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
            CourseId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value = "3" });
            ViewBag.CourseId = CourseId;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Student stud)
        {
            ViewBag.CourseId = stud.CourseId;
            return View();
        }
```

create.cshtml

```html
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseId, "CourseId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.CourseId,new SelectList(ViewBag.CourseId))
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKzOl.png)

I m still facing this error? help
First I run Student Controller it is wrong or not?

Comment: I don't see you putting anything in the `ViewBag` in the controller. Nor you passing a model to the view.

Comment: @GSerg ViewBag.CourseId = stud.CourseId; this line i add in create(Httppost) method still get in error?

Comment: Well courseID is clearly a single integer, not a list of courses. That's the reason for the error. You need to supply a variable containing a list of all the courses you want to show as options in the drop-down. And you should use Html.DropdownListFor instead of Html.DropdownList so you can bind the selected value to the model. Pretty sure you can find lots of examples of this sort of thing online if you look around

Comment: @ADyson i made somechanges in my code and i get an error error is:Value cannot be null.

Comment: Since I can't see your changes it's hard to help

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply Course Id as  SelectListItem in your get action method.Try this

```
public ActionResult Create()
{ 
  List<SelectListItem> CourseId = new List<SelectListItem>();
  CourseId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
  CourseId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
  CourseId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value = "3" });
  ViewBag.CourseId = CourseId;
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Student stud)
{
  ViewBag.CourseId = stud.CourseId;
  return View();
}
```

Comment: run code and then get an error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments and I think data is not bind runtitme CourseId        (DropDownList)->System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem and System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem and System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem

Comment: Weird runs fine for me.Can you share more details

Comment: the problem is in your view try this @Html.DropDownList("CourseId", ViewBag.CourseId as SelectList, "Select Course", new { @class = "form-control" })